# How can share images, messages and urls in ios (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, sdk, share

Please Help us..

We want to share projects (i.e. Its Images, text and also my app url).

But i can't get SDK to share all on whatsApp, facebook, twitter, mails and messages. same as android developer using **Intent called ACTION_SEND**

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
- (void)shareText:(NSString *)text andImage:(UIImage *)image andUrl:(NSURL *)url
    {
        NSMutableArray *sharingItems = [NSMutableArray new];
        if (text) {
            [sharingItems addObject:text];
        }
        if (image) {
            [sharingItems addObject:image];
        }
        if (url) {
            [sharingItems addObject:url];
        }
        UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Call `shareText` like this -

```
[self shareText:@"Your text" andImage:nil andUrl:nil];
```

Comment: it is not working for whatApp. We can't share images using WhatsApp

Comment: You can't share image and text both in WhatsApp using UIActivityViewController. Only single thing you can post. That is image or text.

Comment: WhatsApp has updated policies which doesn't allow simple text to be shared along with Image or URL or Document.

Comment: Yeah, i know. There are many SO questions related to this. But i couldn't find any way of sharing both an image and a text.

Comment: Thanks...If you found please tell me